# EXCEL VBA/ADODB Connection / LEFT JOIN 3 tables SQL - Syntax Error

Tags: sql, left-join, adodb

I have a workbook set up with 3 separate tabs/tables, and I am trying to do a 3 way LEFT JOIN query on this workbook (using SQL via the commandtext box on the ADODB connection in Excel 03), and I get a Syntax Error (Missing Operator) msgbox:

```
SELECT B.[Business], A.[book], C.[bus_area] 

FROM [Bon$] as A LEFT JOIN [DM$] as B ON (A.[book] = B.[SystemBookName] ) 
LEFT JOIN [BA$] as C ON B.[SystemBookName] = C.[portfolio_name]  

WHERE A.[area] NOT LIKE "%TEST%"
```

I know this is probably due to some syntax error/ or where I place the paranthesis, but I tried multiple combinations and it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Remove the `(` in `FROM ([Bon$]`

Comment: Thanks juergen - I have but still got an error. updated my post though.

Answer (score 2):

Ah I figured out why. The code was thrown out because it saw it missing the operator FROM before the **second** LEFT JOIN. So I put in paranthesis everything after FROM and the second LEFT JOIN and it worked.

```
SELECT B.[Business], A.[book], C.[bus_area] 

FROM ([Bon$] as A LEFT JOIN [DM$] as B ON A.[book] = B.[SystemBookName] ) 
LEFT JOIN [BA$] as C ON B.[SystemBookName] = C.[portfolio_name]  

WHERE A.[area] NOT LIKE "%TEST%"
```